# appCache Manifest for Ext JS applications

Tags: caching, extjs

extjs: 6.0.1
senchaCmd: Sencha Cmd v6.1.3.42

I have tryied set this in production config

```
"production": {
   "loader": {
    "cache": "${build.timestamp}"
   }
}
```

and in cache config added same files
[image]

As you can see I have added in production config to cache with the build.timestamp, then files always will have the same _dc parameter. this gives a "timestamp version" for files that will be loaded by microloader.

Microloader always load the app.js_dc?myBuildTimeStampHere.
The manifest file is generated perfectly but the manifest file doesn't put the _dc in cached files
[image]

I need Sencha CMD put the _dc in cached files like this or do not load with _dc parameter.
[image]
Any suggestion to make it automaticaly or tell microloader do not put _dc parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add this line under "loader"

```
"cacheParam": "_dc"
```